# How do I change the StrokeThickness property in a WPF trigger?

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers

When the trigger is on, the `Foreground` property changes, but the `StrokeThickness` property does not. Why is this happening?

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type controls:EdgeControl}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type controls:EdgeControl}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Path Stroke="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                              StrokeThickness="2" MinWidth="1" MinHeight="1"
                              x:Name="PART_edgePath"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="controls:HighlightBehaviour.Highlighted" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="5"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gold"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Use `StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding StrokeThickness}"` in the ControlTemplate, or move the Trigger to `<ControlTemplate.Triggers>`.

Comment: Clemens, thank you very much!  Added `<Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="2"/>` to the beginning of the Style and the Path corrected to `StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding StrokeThickness}"` as you said.